# KDE: Prevent kglobalaccel5 from starting

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, kde5

`kglobalaccel5`, a keyboard shortcut service, keeps chrashing and taking the whole session down with it.
Apparently, it has been unstable for quite a while. I don't really need the shortcuts, so killing the process seems to fix it for me.

However, it is spawned automatically at login and respawns after logging in. Is there a way to disable it altogether?

**Update**
It seems to be a dbus service:

```
# cat /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kglobalaccel.service
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.kde.kglobalaccel
Exec=/usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
```

I'm still not sure how to turn it off though. However since I've started killing it after logging in, I didn't experience any crashes.

While it was running, it could find the following:

```
# pstree -s -p $pid
systemd(1)───systemd(1872)───kglobalaccel5(9450)─┬─{kglobalaccel5}(9451)
                                                 └─{kglobalaccel5}(9452)
```

```
# systemctl status 9450 | grep kglobal
               ├─dbus\x2d:1.2\x2dorg.kde.kglobalaccel.slice
               │ └─dbus-:1.2-org.kde.kglobalaccel@4.service
               │   └─9450 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
```

---

```
Fedora 31, KDE
```

Bugreport with equivalent backtrace: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63280

One of the bugreports as reference: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409448

---

"Bonus question" would be fixing the root problem, if it's not crashing because of a bug.

After the crash, I also find: `This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem`, like in https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63280. However, I'm pretty certain that this is because `Xorg` also crashes and the "expected" environment is gone. It "starts up" normallay but then crashes after some time, usually at the same times as a mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming the dbus service file seems to have done the trick. But I'm not sure how safe this method is in terms of updates and the interaction with KDE. But no crashes anymore.

```
# mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kglobalaccel.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kglobalaccel.service.disable
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
systemctl --user stop 'dbus\x2d:1.2\x2dorg.kde.kglobalaccel.slice'
```

Or 'disable' or 'mask' to make it permanently.